# bpy error, couldnt open display, core dumped

Tags: python, ubuntu, blender, bpy

Hi I'm trying to render something with python module bpy.

I keep getting the error couldn't open display core dumped in my console.

I'm using most recent version of bpy & blender on Ubuntu 20.04 headless. Ive looked everyone can't get an answer on this issue.